# F#: How do I use Map with a Collection (like Regex Matches)?

Tags: f#, dictionary

Soo... F# no longer has IEnumerable.map_with_type... which is the way people *were* mapping over collections. How do I do that now?

```
let urlPat = "href\\s*=\\s*(?:(?:\\\"(?<url>[^\\\"]*)\\\")|(?<url>[^\\s]* ))";;
let urlRegex = new Regex(urlPat)
let matches = 
    urlRegex.Matches(http("http://www.google.com"))

let matchToUrl (urlMatch : Match) = urlMatch.Value
let urls = List.map matchToUrl matches
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you would write the last line like this:

```
let urls = Seq.map matchToUrl (Seq.cast matches);;
```

And this can be written in a nicer way using pipelining operator:

```
let urls = matches|> Seq.cast |> Seq.map matchToUrl;;
```

F# automatically figures out what is the right target type (because it knows what `matchToUrl` looks like). This is available only for Seq, so you can use `List.of_seq` to get the data into a list again.

Answer (score 3):

Is Seq.cast what you are looking for?

Comment: Sounds like it... how would that work? I tried googling but haven't found anything useful.

Comment: See Tomas' answer.  Seq.cast takes an IEnumerable and converts it to IEnumerable<T> (and usually infers the T on your behalf).